# Change SqlDataSource SelectCommand depending on user logged in

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, sqldatasource

I have a existing `SqlDataSource` but the query needs to change depending on the logged in user.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [text] FROM [tblLinks]"
```

Pseudocode:

```
If user = "john.doe"
Then SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [text] FROM [tblLinks] WHERE text <> 'Admin'"
Else 
SelectCommand = "SELECT [id], [text] FROM [tblLinks]"
```

This is my code for getting the current logged in user:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Split("\\").Last()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `SelectCommand` property just like you would any other property in code behind...

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    If (user = "john.doe") Then
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT [id], [text] FROM [tblLinks] WHERE text <> 'Admin'"
    Else
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT [id], [text] FROM [tblLinks]"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

if this helps, I think it's best if you review

```
select...case statement
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx